# Dots for Children in div. A jQuery headache

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I have a simple fading content slider, displaying from images to divs. It works fine, but what I would like to add is the following:

1. Count the (direct) child elements
2. Add a dot holder (div with a class name "imgdotholder") to the parent div (with class name "showContainer").
3. Add a dot (div with a class name "imgdots") for each child in the div.

Exmple of markup:

```
<div class="showContainer">
    <div>Direct Child element 1</div>
    <div>Direct Child element 2</div>
    <div>Direct Child element 3</div>
</div>
```

This is all I've got so far, any help would be much appreciated!

```
var imgCount = $('.showContainer').childern().length;
$('<div class="imgdotholder"><div class="imgdots"></div></div>').appendTo('.showContainer');
```

***EDIT I forgot to add something:***
Exmple of markup again:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="showContainer">
        <div class="blah">Direct Child element 1</div>
        <div class="blah">Direct Child element 2</div>
        <div class="blah">Direct Child element 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A re-run at my problem, I need to do the following:
1) Need to count the child elements in the "showContainer" div
2) Then need to add a div called "imgdotholder" to the "wrapper" div
3) Inside of the "imgdotholder" div I need to add a dot (represented by a div called "imgdots") for each image - say there are 3 images then I need to add 3 dots

Here is a jsfiddle with the basic setup: http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/

Comment: Is `childern` just a typo in your question?

Comment: how should the desired html  look

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U6BMS/1/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Yes sorry, its supposed to be "children"

Comment: @ArunPJohny - its basically a box and the dots should be underneath the box. See this fiddle for a basic layout & structure: http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a loop which iterates for the value `imgCount` :

```
var imgCount = $('.showContainer').children().length; // note: children()
for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
    $('<div class="imgdotholder"><div class="imgdots"></div></div>').appendTo('.showContainer');
}
```

Comment: Instead of the for loop this could be done directly with [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: True, although `each` is effectively a `for` loop anyway. It's real power is iterating over a set of elements in a jQuery object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - I forgot to mention that I have showContainer in a "wrapper" div. If I write it like so (and with a bit of modifying) it could work. thank you! 
`var imgCount = $('.showContainer').children().length; // note: children()
for (var i = 0; i < imgCount; i++) {
    $('<div class="imgdots"></div>').appendTo('.wrapper');
}`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - This is what I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/3/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Is there a way to add an "active" class/id (for css styling purposes) to the "imgdots" div? **As an example:** Say im on image no4 then the 4th "imgdots" div should be a different colour from the rest.

Comment: @Reinhardt there is, although you're probably best to start a new question for that, as it's relatively involved.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
totalSlides = $('.showContainer').length;
```

to get the total slides, then construct an UL  (containing your dots) via a loop

Comment: Hi Pat! Creating the loop is where I am lost.
A fiddle containing a basic setup... to fiddle with:
http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
$('.showContainer').children().each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('<div class="imgdots"></div>');
});
```

**EDIT**

Let's see if I understand

```
// Count of the direct children of .showContainer , If you need
var imgCount = $('.showContainer').length;

// Append the .imgdotholder to the .wrapper
$('.wrapper').append('<div class="imgdotholder"></div>');

// Iterate over all the children and in each step append an .imgdots to the .imgdotholder
$('.showContainer').children().each(function(){
    $('.wrapper .imgdotholder').append('<div class="imgdots"></div>');
});
```