# Dots for Children in div. A jQuery headache - PART 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So this is part 2 of my previous question (was advised to start a new question for this one).
Just for reference here is my previous post: [Dots for Children in div. A jQuery headache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270277/dots-for-children-in-div-a-jquery-headache)
**My question now is:** 
 How does one go about adding an "active" class/id to the "imgdots" div for styling purposes?
**For example:**
Say I'm on image 4 then I want the 4th "imgdots" div to be another colour.
Again, any help would be much appreciated! 
 **EDIT**
I have set up a fiddle containing what I have thus far. The initial image *slider* was from a tutorial I followed and kinda pieced it all together from there. 
 Here is the link: jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/8/

Comment: do you mean when you hover an `imgdots` element? or do you mean `blah` element

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WaM5p/2/ or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WaM5p/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - No not quite. If you look at my new [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/8/) you'll see 5 divs or slides and each div/slide is represented by a dot at the bottom. When the slideshow reaches slide no 4 for example I would like to change the 4th dot colour from black to say red.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5qnav/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Thanks for looking into this, its looks pretty groovy! Is there a way to get rid of the popping through of the background that occurs, with maybe a crossfade between images? The fiddle I ended up with in the meantime: http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/

Comment: if the delay is more then I think it loos fine... else I don't see a solution as there it done by jQuery animation

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Is there a way to _link_ the dots with the slides and how complicated would it be to do? **EG:** if you click on dot 4 it goes to slide 4

Comment: what should happen to the loop then... should it stop? and start again on mouse leave

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yes, if possible... thats normally done by the _clear interval_ exercise right?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5qnav/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Thank you very much, you are a legend! If possible would you mind commenting the script section a bit in the fiddle? I'd really like to go through it and learn about what was done there.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - I found a cross fade solution. I found that if you change the code on line 28 (on your fiddle) from `$views.eq(current).hide();` to `$views.eq(current).fadeOut();` it works. Thanks again for all your help, this forum rocks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
/* The jQuery plugin */
(function ($) {
    $.fn.simpleShow = function (settings) {
        var config = {
            'tranTimer': 5000,
            'tranSpeed': 'normal'
        };
        if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);
        this.each(function () {
            var $wrapper = $(this),
                $ct = $wrapper.find('.showContainer'),
                $views = $ct.children();
            var viewCount = $views.length;

            var $imgdotholder = $('<div class="imgdotholder"></div>').appendTo('.wrapper');
            for (var i = 0; i < viewCount; i++) {
                $('<div class="imgdots"></div>').appendTo($imgdotholder);
            }
            var $imgdots = $imgdotholder.children();

            var timer, current = 0;

            function loop() {
                timer = setInterval(next, config.tranTimer);
            }

            function next(idx) {
                $views.eq(current).hide();

                current = idx == undefined ? current + 1 : idx;
                if (isNaN(current) || current < 0 || current >= viewCount) {
                    current = 0;
                }

                $views.eq(current).fadeIn(config.tranSpeed);
                $imgdots.removeClass('current').eq(current).addClass('current');
            }

            $imgdots.click(function(){
                clearInterval(timer);
                next($(this).index());
            })

            $wrapper.find('.btn_nxt').click(function(){
                clearInterval(timer);
                next();
            });
            $ct.hover(function(){
                clearInterval(timer);
            }, loop);

            $views.slice(1).hide();
            $imgdots.eq(0).addClass('current');
            loop();
        });
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

/* Calling The jQuery plugin */
$(document).ready(function () {
    /**/
    $(".wrapper").simpleShow({
        'tranTimer': 3000,
        'tranSpeed': 800
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5qnav/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen nth child css?

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

```
#showContainer:nth-child(4)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: thats only if he wants the dots in 4, 8, 12, 16 etc. my class only does the one in 4th position

Comment: As mentioned to ArunP above: If you look at my new [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Reinhardt/cgt5M/8/) you'll see 5 divs or slides and each div/slide is represented by a dot at the bottom. When the slideshow reaches slide no 4 for example I would like to change the 4th dot colour from black to say red.

Comment: ah i see what you mean, could you associate each div and dot with another property for an ID, then when the active div changes, you can add/remove a class from the dot based on ID to change the colour

Comment: @WraithNath - Well I ended up with something that works in a similar fashion... but ArunPJohny has a pretty groovy solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5qnav/2